# What am I doing wrong to join my 3 tables?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am having issues writing a very simple SQL query that Selects all the columns in all three tables and JOINs the three tables in the database I created and uses BETWEEN to filter record selection using Date of Birth to filter data.

These are my tables:

--This Code Creates the Stores table--

```
CREATE TABLE [SHATTKudlerFineFoods].dbo.tblStores 
(
strStoreID varchar (4) CONSTRAINT PK_strStoreID PRIMARY KEY Not Null,
strStoreName varchar (20) Not Null,
strManagerName varchar (30) Not Null
)
```

--This Code Creates the Job Title Table--

```
CREATE TABLE [SHATTKudlerFineFoods].dbo.tblJobTitle
(
jobJobID varchar (4) CONSTRAINT PK_jobJobID PRIMARY KEY Not Null,
jobJobClass varchar (60) Not Null,
jobTitle varchar (60) Not Null,
jobDescription varchar (300) Not Null,
jobStatus varchar (11) Not Null
)
```

--This Code Creates the Employee Table--

```
CREATE TABLE [SHATTKudlerFineFoods].dbo.tblEmployee
(
empEmpID varchar (3) CONSTRAINT PK_empEmployeeID PRIMARY KEY Not Null,
empLName varchar (20) Not Null,
empFName varchar (15) Not Null,
empAddress varchar (30) Not Null,
empCity varchar (20) Not Null,
empState varchar (2) Not Null,
empZIPCode varchar (5) Not Null,
empAreaCode varchar (3) Not Null,
empPhoneNo varchar (8) Not Null,
empGender varchar (1) Not Null,
empDOB smalldatetime Not Null,
empAge Tinyint Not Null,
empHireDate smalldatetime Not Null,
empNoOfExempt Tinyint Not Null,
empMaritalStatus varchar (3) Not Null,
empSalary money Not Null,
empStoreID varchar (4) CONSTRAINT FK_strStoreID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES
tblStores(strStoreID) Not Null,
empJobID varchar (4) CONSTRAINT FK_jobJobID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
tblJobTitle(jobJobID) Not Null
)
```

This is the query I wrote to join them:

```
USE [SHATTKudlerFineFoods]
SELECT *
FROM tblStores INNER JOIN tblEmployee
ON tblStores.strStoreID = tblEmployee.empStoreID
FULL OUTER JOIN tblStores
ON tblStores.strStoreID = tblJobTitle.ordStoreID
WHERE empDOB BETWEEN '1/1/1985' and '1/1/1999'
```

Comment: `tblJobTitle` used in the second `ON` is not in the `FROM` list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um, your tables are wrong in the join.  Is that a typo?

```
SELECT *
FROM tblStores INNER JOIN tblEmployee
ON tblStores.strStoreID = tblEmployee.empStoreID
FULL OUTER JOIN tblJobTitle
ON tblEmployee.empJobId = tblJobTitle.jobJobId;
```

The third reference should be `tblJobTitle` rather than `tblStores`, I think, along with the right columns for connecting them.

Comment: No, it is not. My materials are confusing I was pretty sure this was the issue but it would be nice if someone could explain it to me. My instructor hasn't replied all week and I'm kind of desperate.

Comment: @LynetteShatto . . . the simplest advice is to follow the foreign key relationships in the table creation.  These often tell you how to join the tables.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "tblJobTitle.jobJobID" could not be bound.
Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The objects "tblStores" and "tblStores" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Comment: @LynetteShatto The problem in your original query is that the second JOIN is with `tblStores`, when it should be with `tblJobTitle`. That's what both Gordon and Felipe have fixed in their answers.

Comment: I thought they were merely quoting my query ... feel stupid now!

Comment: This works now, no errors. I am still having a difficult time understanding this as all my materials only explain joining two tables but at least I can continue on writing my other assigned queries thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblStores INNER JOIN tblEmployee
ON tblStores.strStoreID = tblEmployee.empStoreID
FULL OUTER JOIN tblJobTitle
ON tblEmployee.empJobID = tblJobTitle.jobJobID
WHERE empDOB BETWEEN '1/1/1985' and '1/1/1999'
```

This is what I imagine that could be useful

Comment: My answer was in part a question too because I wasn't sure if that was what you were looking for, this query fits your needs?

Comment: I am joining all the tables listed above, yes, but I am confused as to how to write the query to do so.

Comment: @LynetteShatto No, you're not joining all the tables. Look carefully, you're not joining `tblJobTitle`, you're joining `tblStores` there.

Comment: I see what you mean now, I didn't realize you had fixed this in your reply.

Comment: Don't worry, try it and see if it return the data you need